# Ada - Subtype mark required in this context

Tags: ada

I'm trying to make a simple looping program but get the error on line 18, subtype mark required in this context, but I don't get this error when running other programs?

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

with Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;

procedure main is
input   : Unbounded_String;

begin

    while input not in "!Close" loop --Line 18
    Get_Line(input);
end loop;

end main;
```

Comment: Back in the Good Old Days, all membership tests had the form `<value> in <subtype>`, which is where this error message comes from. Now membership tests are more complex, but GNAT's error msg hasn't kept up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a membership test, both values must be of the same type. In your case,
`input` is an `Unbounded_String`, while `"!Close"` is a string literal.
You either have to convert one of them into the other, or just use the  equality operator defined in `Ada.Strings.Unbounded`
(And since you've already done `use Ada.Strings.Unbounded` you have visibility of all the alternatives):

```ada
while input not in To_Unbounded_String("!Close") loop --Line 18
```

or

```ada
while To_String(input) not in "!Close" loop --Line 18
```

or

```ada
while input /= "!Close" loop --Line 18
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The first two versions may work, but to me they look completely bizarre! And isn’t a type conversion needed for the third version?

Comment: The first two is allowed in Ada 2012, see [AI05-0158](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai05s/ai05-0158-1.txt?rev=1.20). In the case above, the membership_choice_list contains only one value, which I guess may look weird. The last one uses the equals operator defined in Ada.Strings.Unbounded, `function "="  (Left : in Unbounded_String; Right : in String)
     return Boolean;`